# How could this macro be rewritten in modern C++?

Tags: c++, macros, refactoring, porting

We have a macro in our C++17 codebase that says:

```
#define APOT_DEF(Type, Member) alignas(NextPow2(sizeof(Type))) Type Member
```

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality in modern C++ without the use of a macro?

Would a function or a combination of a function and a type be able to accomplish this?

Comment: That can't really be converted to a function, since it's used to define variables.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude C++14 and later do support [variable templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template), though. Maybe that can be utilized to replace the macro?

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's true, perhaps used as a type-alias? That should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be replaced perfectly. The issue is that the `alignas` attribute can only be applied in two places. To the declaration of a (member) varaible, or to the declaration of a class type. So a potential replacement may be something like this:

```
template<typename Type>
struct alignas (NextPow2(sizeof(Type))) ApotDef {
    Type mem;
    operator Type& () & { return mem; }
    operator Type const& () const& { return mem; }
    operator Type&& () && { return std::move(mem); }
    // Maybe for volatile?
};
```

So every occurrence of of `APOT_DEF(Type, Member)` may be replaced by `ApotDef<Type> Member;`. This will allow `ApotDef<Type>` to be used in many of the same places `Type` itself could be used, but it's not a drop in replacement. There will be instances (most involving type deduction) where the conversions to a `Type` glvalue won't trigger.

So if the exact type of the member is important to you, I'd stick to the macro. I would however change it a bit to make declaration slightly more "C++" and less a DSL that wraps C++. I'd use this macro:

```
#define APOT_ALIGNED(Type) alignas(NextPow2(sizeof(Type))) Type
```

So variable declaration will at least have the form of a declaration:

```
APOT_ALIGNED(Type) member;
```